# Fitting all items into one collection view row

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

Is there a way to make all items in a collection view fit in one row and not automatically place items in an another row? I'm trying to copy something like Instagram's story display like the link below:

[image]

However, In my collection view, I'm getting a count from a server, and displaying the information in a collection view but it always goes to the next line after 3 items are displayed.

```
// number of sections function
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictures.count
    } // end of function
```

Comment: Do some searching on setting the width of the items in the collection view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't want Vertical scrolling in Collection view.

For horizontal scrolling in collection view, select collection view in storyboard and change `scroll direction` to horizontal.

Refer this below pic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can add collectionViewLayout delegate method like this. CGFloat(3.0) is how many item you want, you have to divide it from collectionView's width

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemWidth: CGFloat = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width)  / CGFloat(3.0))
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)
}
```